# Why is a voltage across emitter and base required in a bipolar transistor?

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn

I read the reply to this question but I cannot really make sense of it:
[In an NPN transistor, why doesn't current flow without applying a base voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/416148/in-an-npn-transistor-why-doesnt-current-flow-without-applying-a-base-voltage)

If I have an NPN transistor and and apply a voltage between emitter and collector which is let's say 10 V, why is no charge flowing from emitter to the base already?

As I understand the PN junction between base and collector, it is in reverse bias due to the external voltage and will not allow any holes from the base or electrons from the collector to cross the barrier. If due to a voltage between base and emitter bigger than 0.7 V, however, electrons flow into the base they can drain through the collector.

Now, why can't the applied emitter-collector voltage cause flow of electrons into the base (in a sense of pushing the electrons from the emitter over the potential barrier just as in a forward biased diode?) Then we would have free electrons in the base that could then flow to the collector.

Comment: *why can't the applied emitter-collector voltage not cause flow of electrons into the base* **because** *the pn junction between base and collector, it is in reverse bias due to the external voltage*. Note how I just copy-pasted two sections from your question.

Comment: Thanks. The pn junction between base and collector is in reverse bias as you highlight but the junction between emitter and base is not. So I can only understand that current does not flow through THAT first junction but not why electrons wouldn't flow through the base emitter junction from the emitter)

Comment: You might expand your question to the case where the emitter-collector voltage is small -- say 200 mV. It still won't conduct. The reason is that the base region quickly arranges itself so that there is no shared conduction energy band between collector and emitter and so no current can flow. You have to restore the situation by continually supplying a small recombination current at the base or else it almost instantly becomes a barrier (there will be a very very tiny charge flow for a moment before that happens) and the only way to restore things is to supply that recombination current.

Comment: Both junctions are in series.

Comment: *the junction between emitter and base is not* OK, so what keeps that BE junction in forward? It can't be the CE junction because it is in reverse mode. Note that the only current from the CE junction is a **leakage** current. Is that enough to make the BE junction operate properly in "forward mode" or would more current be needed? If I wanted to "pull" the BE junction into "proper" forward mode, what would I need to do? Hint: it has to do with the base connection.

Comment: Yes, in the normal operation the BE-voltage of 0.7V+ keeps the BE-junction in forward-bias. But I fail to see why the C-E voltage cannot do that job --> Can the negative terminal not push the electrons into the base just like in the normal operation with a BE-voltage?. By the way what are you referring to as the CE-junction? Isn't there only a BE and BC junction?

Comment: The CE was a typo! Just read it as "CB". To get a Vbe of ~ 0.7 V you need **a lot** more current than the reverse biased CB junction leakage current. So when the base isn't connected to anything, the CB junction determines the current and it will only allow for a **very small** current. To get the transistor into active mode the BE junction needs to be well into forward mode. The CB leakage current cannot do that, it is too small.

Comment: In general, a current within a BJT cannot cause anything - it is always a voltage that is the cause of the various effects to be observed. Each current is always the result of a voltage - externally applied or internally effective. Perhaps the only exception from this rule is the movement of charged particles called "diffusion current" -  responsible for the barrier at the pn-junction. However, this is another type of current and cannot be compared with all the currents which do exist while the BJT is working.

Comment: Without the base voltage explicitly applied, you have one diode going to the supply and another to ground.  The one going to supply is reverse biased, and passes little current, so the other one will keep the base voltage at essentially ground.

Comment: The bipolar transistor is a particle accelerator, those particles flowing between base and emitter. As those particles flow, there are oppositely charged particles, sitting at high voltage in the collector, ready to attack and annihilate the base-emitter particles as the two opposite polarities seek out and cancel each other. **HOWEVER** most of the attacking particles **MISS**, continuing their rapid journey across the base region and ending up in the emitter, to become a usefully larger (amplified) copy of the base current.

Comment: Can anyone post an answer less than a mile long?

Comment: Alright thanks to everyone so far. @CristobolPolychronopolis I think that might be what my misunderstanding is but could you elaborate a little? If I draw the transistor as two diodes and an external voltage supply how can I see that the base voltage will be kept at ground? I drew that circuit but I cannot quite figure out what you mean..

Comment: @OskarBergmann Actually, if the base is open (unconnected) in an NPN with (+) to collector and (-) to emitter, the base will be slightly positive with respect to the emitter. Perhaps \$+60\:\text{mV}\$? Thereabouts. (Not easy to measure.)

Comment: If you consider the diodes as ideal, you will see that the junction of the anodes provides an easy path to ground, but blocks current from the supply.  That keeps that junction at ground level.  In real life, there is a small amount of leakage, but not enough to trigger the amplification process.