# Why Collector-to-Base currents ratio in a BJT transistor always greater than 1?

Tags: transistors, bjt, physics

According to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/83268):

> Note that the holes injected into Emitter are supplied from Base
>   electrode (Base current), whereas the electrons injected into the Base
>   are supplied from Emitter electrode (Emitter current). The ratio
>   between these currents is what makes BJT a current amplifying device -
>   small current at Base terminal can cause a much higher current at
>   Emitter terminal. The conventional current amplification is defined as
>   Collector-to-Base currents ratio, but it is the ratio between the
>   above currents which makes any current amplification possible.

First off, Why collector current increases as base current increase? Is the former causes the later, or the later causes the former, or something else (voltage on electrodes, maybe) causes both?

And here is my question, Why collector current always increases **more than** the increment of base current? Say after something changes, `a` extra holes are "injected into" emitter region, and `b` extra electrons are injected into base region. Then why `b` is greater to `a`?