# We fabricate P-type and N-type Schottky diodes and a P-type Schottky diode; can a PN-junction diode and PNP BJT be formed?

Tags: transistors, diodes, schottky, bipolar, fabrication

A Schottky diode is a unipolar device. If a P-type Schottky diode is fabricated on an N-type Schottky diode, can we make a PN-junction diode and a PNP transistor?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78366/why-cant-two-series-connected-diodes-act-as-a-bjt/

Comment: Don't understand the question completely. Perhaps make a sketch... Is that sketch similar to the first one here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_transistor ?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot make a pure silicon PN out of a Schottky PN as the latter has one layer metalized and a lower threshold . No you cannot make a PNP out of 2 diodes, But you can make a weak and strong diode pair out of a PNP with a common N.